# Functions with appropriate parameters

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Hello everyone I have more of a question. I am working with functions and events now this is what I have so far..

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <title>Personal Information</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="js_styles.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   function printPeronalinfo( "name,age,hobbies,favorite movies") {
   document.write("<p>" + name +"</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + age +"</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + hobbies + "</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + favorite video + "</p>");
   }
   //]]>
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    / * <![CDATA[ */
   printPeronalinfo( "age,age,hobbies,favorite movies")
   var return_value = return_message();
   document.write(return_value);
   /*]]> */

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Now the question I have is I know I am doing something wrong cause it is not showing up on a web page. It is suppose to read my name,age, hobbies, favorite movies. Now do I repeat what I have in the head to the body but instead of the word name I will put my name in there or do I use the if or else(but I am pretty sure that is for the buttons). I also know that I can use an array but I don't know if that would work or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes..

```
function printPeronalinfo( "name,age,hobbies,favorite movies") {
/*                         ^ no quotes here, ^ invalid variable name */
// should be: function printPeronalinfo(name, age, hobbies, favorite_movies) {
   document.write("<p>" + name +"</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + age +"</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + hobbies + "</p>");
   document.write("<p>" + favorite video + "</p>");
   /*                     ^ undefined variable, isn't defined in your function */
   // should be: document.write("<p>" + favorite_movies + "</p>");
}
```

...

```
printPeronalinfo( "age,age,hobbies,favorite movies");
/*                ^ incorrect passing of data */
// should be: printPeronalinfo("name", "age", "hobbies", "favorite movies");
```

You should also be aware that your function name misspells "Personal" as "Peronal".

**Update:** In your 2nd `<script>` block, you have an incorrect comment-block tag: `/ *` should not have a space. This is correct: `/*`

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my end.

Comment: Ok thanks you can you be able to give some ideas on how to be creative with this. Do you think the window prompt would work good

Comment: That's difficult to say.. We've had to make basic corrections to your `syntax`, which says a lot about the limitations of your javascript knowledge. It seems to me like you should use this as a learning tool, and not try to turn it into something that you want others to use.

Comment: ok yeah i am the start of javascript.. so i am still learning it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes from around your function parameters:

```
function printPeronalinfo( name,age,hobbies,favoritemovies)
```

Then call the function like this:

```
printPeronalinfo( "name","age","hobbies","favorite movies")
```

Comment: ok i did that but nothing still came up.I know it is something simple I am just trying to figure it out.

Comment: the favorite movies parameter must not have any spaces in the name, such as favoriteMovies

Comment: ummm I thought this will be a little easier but I guess not..now do i need to use a var to put them in separte then.

Comment: yes, each parameter should be in a separate var that you can pass into the function as a parameter.

Comment: Now do i put that in the head or body part. And thank you for explaining this too me.